# How to read a value with scanf and store it in a variable which was allocated dynamically in C?

Tags: c

Why this code isn't working? After entering the value, program crashes. 
I'm just learning programming btw.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int* p;
  p=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  printf("Enter a value : \n");
  scanf("%d", *p);
  printf("%d", *p);
}
```

Comment: What do you need to pass to `scanf`? Hint: It's not `p`'s non-existent value, which results in undefined behavior.

Comment: If you use normal variable `int v;` you'd write `scanf("%d", &v); printf("%d", v);`. Do you see a pattern here?

Comment: @MichaelWalz , Yes now i got it right, i was confused with the * operator

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` should have address, not value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int* p;
  p=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  printf("Enter a value : \n");
  scanf("%d", p);
  printf("%d", *p);
  free(p); // should free manually
}
```

Comment: Now i understand which was the problem, thank you for your quick answer

Comment: Always a good idea to check the return value from `scanf("%d", p);`  (is it 1?) before using `*p` in `printf("%d", *p);`.